# why makefile function also works in recipe part?

Tags: makefile

According to the doc, in the recipe part, the code after a tab is send to shell. Then shell should not know makefile function. For example

```
a:
<tab>$(info ===)
```

if I run `make a`, it outputs

```
===
make: `a' is up to date.
```

Why? Shell doesn't know `$(info ===)`, why it can output `===`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(info ...)` isn't being interpreted by shell, it is actually a special function in `make`. The info function prints the expanded arguments, which in this case are just a constant `===` back to the console.  Here is an excerpt from the GNU documentation:

> This function does nothing more than print its (expanded) argument(s) to standard output... The result of the expansion of this function is the empty string.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html).

Comment: Hi, Derek Brown. Thank you for answering. But I don't understand. This is not consistent with the doc https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Execution.html#Execution Which says each line is executed by subshell

Comment: @user15964 each line is executed by a subshell.  However, before each line is passed into a sub-shell, `make` processes its own variable and method call syntax, which takes either the form `$(...)` or `${...}`.  You can read about this more here https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html#Variables-in-Recipes

Comment: But this cause another problem. If `$(info ===)` is interpreted by make first, it becomes `===`. If this `===` is passed to shell, this is an unrecognized command, and will cause an error message. But in fact make doesn't complain about this. So `===` doesn't send to shell, right? But the example in your link ` for i in $(LIST); do \` is first expanded, then send to shell. This is not consistent

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain this a little better, but as the GNU documentation describes, the `$(info ...)` function logs any input to the console, and returns an empty string.  So all that is actually sent to the sub-shell is an empty string, which doesn't trigger an error.